# Why does Javascript add an extra backslash when I capture input values?

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

I have a standard HTML input form. The issue occurs when I enter something like `\n` in the input. I'm aware it's a regex that means newline, but a user may for example have it in their password, and it should remain unchanged.

The behaviour I'm observing:

```
const value = $('#myInput').val()
console.log(value)   // Console shows: hello\n (which is indeed what the user typed in)
const outputData = { password: value }
console.log(outputData)   // Console shows: { password: "hello\\n"}
```

It would be fine if it were just a display issue, but that data is being sent to the server with the double backslash, so there is a mismatch between what the user types in and what gets sent to the server (which of course breaks things).

It's also worth noting this doesn't happen (everything works as expected) when I send a request body via Postman

1. Why is this happening?
2. How can I avoid it?

Comment: It does not add anything, the extra \ is just displayed differently depending on the context, e.g. when in between " to signal that this is a string.

Comment: It would be fine if it were indeed just a display issue, but that data is being sent to the server with the double backslash, so there is a mismatch between what the user types in and what gets sent to the server (which of course breaks things).
However, you make a good point - I should specify this in my question

Comment: No, there is one literal \ in that string. Write code to count the number of \ if you want or check the string length. If you see it one the server then probably for the exact same reason, because of display logic.

Comment: Fair, but it's getting saved in my database with a double-backslash and causing a mismatch later on. In any case, will try writing server-side logic to replace double backslashes with backslashes

Comment: May not be answering directly to the question, but limiting the type of characters used in password and usernames could save you alot of trouble. Special chars like "\" are just problems unless you escape and unescape it correctly. Common chars allowed are #,@,^,!,?,,%....

Comment: @SomeoneSpecial fair point, but it unfortunately can't be avoided. In this case users will be uploading keys from other services (they'll be stored securely) which will have backslashes

Comment: @SomeoneSpecial - If you properly handle the string, the characters in the string are completely irrelevant. There is no special care required to handle backslashes, emojis, or other "special" characters. Code that seems to break when presented with a backslash in an input is *already* broken, and should be fixed regardless of whether you want backslashes in passwords.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Re the code comments in the code you shared:

```js
const value = $('#myInput').val()
console.log(value)   // Console shows: hello\n (which is indeed what the user typed in)
const outputData = { password: value }
console.log(outputData)   // Console shows: { password: "hello\\n"}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="myInput" value="hello\n">
```

I assume you're referring to this style of console output:

[image: Browser console showing hello\n for the first log call, but {password: 'hello\\n'} for the second]

That's just the difference between how the Chrome console (and some others) displays the output when you pass it a string vs. when you pass it an object. JavaScript is not adding anything to the string. When you pass a string to `console.log`, it just shows the characters of the string (which in your case are `h`, `e`, `l`, `l`, `o`, `\`, and `n`). But when you pass it an object, it shows you something that looks like an object literal, and since the object literal contains a string *literal* for `password`, the backslash in the string *literal* has to be shown escaped. (Otherwise, it would be an escape character.) But there is only one backslash in the string, not two, exactly like this:

```js
console.log("hello\\n"); // <== Notice the escaped backslash
```

The backslash is escaped in the string literal, because otherwise it wouldn't be a backslash, it would be an escape character changing the meaning of the next character (in this case, putting a newline in the string rather than `\` and `n`.) There is only one backslash in the string.

> It would be fine if it were just a display issue, but that data is being sent to the server with the double backslash...

Two possibilities here:

1. The extra backslash is being added by code you haven't shown, either the code preparing the string to send to your server, or the code on the server writing it to the database. For instance, another answer posted to this question suggested doing `JSON.stringify(value)`, but that **would** add an extra backslash to it for the same reason we put on in a string literal: you have to escape backslashes in JSON strings. The extra one would be removed if the server code parsed the JSON, but it wouldn't be if the server code used the string as-is. I'm not saying you're doing that, just that it's the *kind* of thing you could be doing to see what you're describing.
2. Or — with apologies! :-) — it's possible that you're misinterpreting what you're seeing for what's in the database in the same way you misinterpeting the object literal in the console and there is actually only one backslash in the database.

Your best bet for finding out what's causing the problem is to carefully audit the code processing the string, in particular:

- Check the actual value of the string with a debugger just prior to sending it to the server.
- Check how you're encoding what you're sending the server.
- Check exactly what your code on the server is receiving.
- Check what that code is doing to the string when adding the value to the database.

Somewhere along the line, you'll either determine there isn't actually a problem (#2 above), or you'll find out what's mistakenly adding the backslash (#1 above).

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer, it helps a lot.
The reason why I think it's neither 1 nor 2 (though please correct me if I'm wrong) - and it's rather something happening on the client side - is that everything works fine when I send the request via Postman. i.e. when I look at the request body on the debugger, it shows `hello\n` on the server-side logs. But when I send it via jQuery Ajax, it shows `hello\\n` on both the client-side and server-side console.

Comment: If you send json, than it has to be escaped backslash, no confusion.

Comment: @kgaspard - That's good debugging! But rather than ruling out #1, it rules it in. :-) It tells you that client code is adding the backslash before/during sending it to the server, similar to the hypothetical JSON scenario I described (which, again, probably isn't what you're actually doing, it's just one way this kind of thing can turn up). So it sounds like the code is encoding the string before sending, and the server code isn't decoding it on receipt (or at least, not correctly). So you'll want to track down where it's being encoded (`$.ajax` does some automatic encoding) and either...

Comment: ...turn that off, or use the relevant decoding in the server code.

Comment: You're right, it rules #2 out and #1 in...looking through it now!

Comment: @kgaspard - Yup, which is a very useful step forward. :-)

Answer (score -2):

A big thanks to all of you who helped me find the answer, especially to [@T.J. Crowder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157247/t-j-crowder) for walking me through the steps.

The issue was indeed with the backslash being escaped, but it wasn't a simple display issue. Given that values with a single backslash (like `hello\n`) inputted on the front end form were showing up on the server like `hello\\n`, but values with a single backslash sent from *Postman* would show up correctly on the server like `hello\n` (correctly), there was something happening on the client side.

In addition, hardcoding the input on the client side with a single backslash (e.g. `data: { input: "hello\n" }`) then sending it to the server would show up correctly with a single slash on the server, confirming it was a front-end, likely jQuery issue.

It turns out that, when grabbing the input value, jQuery automatically escapes backslashes and special characters.

As [@Someone Special](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2822041/someone-special) pointed out, the "right" solution here would be to prevent users from inputting backslashes and saving ourselves the headache. However - for reasons too long to go into here - users would have to input backslashes - or at least `\n` - for this use case, so we had to handle it somehow.

What I ended up doing: factoring in for the special characters we were expecting. We knew we had to account for `\n` and `\t`, so we created this function and wrapped `$(input).val()`s with it where necessary:

```
const unescapeString = (str) => {
    return str
        .replace(/\\n/g, String.fromCharCode(10))
        .replace(/\\t/g, String.fromCharCode(9))
}
```

It's not perfect as it doesn't account for all possible cases and we'll have to update it with other special characters if the need arises for them later on, but it works for now.

Comment: *"It turns out that, when grabbing the input value, jQuery automatically escapes backslashes and special characters."* No, it doesn't. That would be **massively** broken, and you can see that it doesn't by the output of the code in your question. *"As @Someone Special pointed out, the "right" solution here would be to prevent users from inputting backslashes and saving ourselves the headache."* No, that would only sweep the problem under the rug. If you handle the string properly, it doesn't matter what the characters in the string are. If you find an issue like this, it means the code...

Comment: ...handling the string is broken and needs fixing. With respect, the above is a bandaid, not a solution, and it'll fail as soon as something is input that you don't expect (like `\f`, or `\u00A`). Instead, find the actual problem, where the actual backslash is added, and fix that.

Comment: *"In addition, hardcoding the input on the client side with a single backslash (e.g. `data: { input: "hello\n" })`..."* That string doesn't have a backslash in it. It has an escape sequence forming a newline.

Comment: Understood, and agreed the current 'solution' is a band-aid. However, as far as I can tell, there's no way to prevent jQuery from 'adding' that backslash when taking the input `val()`. Though if I can find a way, that would be the right solution

Comment: *"However, as far as I can tell, there's no way to prevent jQuery from 'adding' that backslash when taking the input `val()`"* Again: [it doesn't](https://jsfiddle.net/tjcrowder/1kL8rx02/). So the first step to figuring out what's actually going on is to let go of the belief that it does. Something is clearly encoding the string in some way (JSON or similar) before sending it to the server, but it **isn't** `val()`.

Comment: Thanks, the JSFiddle helps illustrate this. Back to the drawing board...